# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) is causing my scanf to fail

Tags: c, int, scanf, calculator, exc-bad-access

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    bool isTrue=true;
    int nums[50];
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(nums); i++) {
        nums[i]=2147483647;
    }
    char operations[49];
    int counter = 0;
    printf("What is your first number? (THERE IS NO PEMDAS, THE NUMBER 2147483647 is not allowed)\n");
    scanf("%d", &nums[counter]); // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
}
```

I have more code, but it is unrelated to the problem. Thank you for helping and just ask if more info is needed (I am making a calculator that lines up inputs and calcultes them 
eg. 3 + 5 * 9 / 2 = 36. The equation can have at most 50 integers and 49 operations.)

Comment: `i<sizeof(nums)` should be `i<sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0])`

Comment: Don't give us half of your function. Give us all of it. Or at least make it compile with only half.

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking the size of your array in bytes, not in the number of elements. Do this instead:

```
for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(nums) / sizeof(nums[0]); i++ )
{
```